# How to add information to a cell based on information in other cells in the column using R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a very messy dataframe that looks like

```
df <- data.frame(Job = c("casual", "part time", "full time", "Level A total" , "casual","full time","Level B total"), institute1 = c(1,2,2,5,0,1,1))
```

Where the rows above "Level B total" refer to level B, until going up the rows you get to "level A total" where it now refers to level A. The data is >500 lines long so manually cleaning it is an option but an unpleasant one, but I cant think of how to code it so I can add information so R knows what Level each cell is referring to.

Comment: What is your expected output for the given data?

Comment: Just adding "Level x" to every Job cell, so I can easily subset the data based on the level. so it would be Job = c"Level A casual","Level A part time" )etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a new column `Level` and put all the `"Level"` values in it. `fill` the `NA` values with the non-NA value below it. Clean up the `Level` column by adding text from `Job`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Level = replace(Job, !grepl('Level', Job), NA)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(Level, .direction = 'up')  %>%
  mutate(Level = ifelse(grepl('total', Job), 
                        Job, paste0(sub('total', '', Level), Job)))

#            Job institute1             Level
#1        casual          1    Level A casual
#2     part time          2 Level A part time
#3     full time          2 Level A full time
#4 Level A total          5     Level A total
#5        casual          0    Level B casual
#6     full time          1 Level B full time
#7 Level B total          1     Level B total
```

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much solves everything. Im new to pipes how do you save that transformed data to the environment so I can use it later?

Comment: `df1 <- df %>% mutate(Level = replace(Job, !grepl('Level', Job), NA))....rest of the code`. So the transformed data is in `df1`.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
transform(within(df[rev(seq_len(nrow(df))),], 
           {
             Level <- ifelse(grepl("Level\\s*[A-Z]", Job), 
                             gsub("\\s*total", "", Job), NA_character_)
            }
          ), Level = na.omit(Level)[cumsum(!(is.na(Level)))])[rev(seq_len(nrow(df))),]
```